Unable to Launch Anaconda Navigator
I recently downloaded a new package to my python environment (climlab, although I doubt this is the reason for my problem). When I did so, it prompted me to update my conda environment. I do so with the command 'conda update -n base -c defaults conda' After running this, I now receive the following error when trying to run the anaconda navigator
(base) cope9081@UCB-C02F7289MD6M ~ % anaconda-navigator
pip_system_certs: ERROR: could not register module: No module named 'wrapt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 7, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py", line 27, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
  File "/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
  File "/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/client_api.py", line 23, in <module>
    import binstar_client
  File "/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binstar_client/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .requests_ext import NullAuth
  File "/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binstar_client/requests_ext.py", line 11, in <module>
    from urllib3.filepost import choose_boundary, iter_fields
ImportError: cannot import name 'iter_fields' from 'urllib3.filepost' (/Users/cope9081/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/filepost.py)

I've tried a few solutions based on ideas here, but no luck. I'm worried the environment broke in some way when I ran the update and I will have to start over and reinstall everything. I have two environments (base and research) that are important to maintain. Any advice would be appreciated.
Some things I tried included restarting my computer and running ' conda install pyqt --force-reinstall' One thing I have considered is deleted my Anaconda installation, then downloading it again. However, I'm worried I'll lose the environments.
Let me know if there are any additional pieces of information that would be helpful for me to include

do conda list and check if either urllib3 or binstar_client show PyPi as channel
